# jetty-maven-plugin source code repository

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

Does anybody know where to find the source code repository of the Jetty Maven plugin? I'm searching for the real source code repo if available, not for the *-sources.jar file which is available [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/8.1.3.v20120416/jetty-maven-plugin-8.1.3.v20120416-sources.jar).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jetty @ Eclipse: (org.eclipse.jetty.*)

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/

Jetty @ Codehaus: (org.mortbay.jetty.*)

https://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/jetty-project

(mirrored since codehaus git http browsing is broke and for reporting reasons atm)

https://github.com/jmcc0nn3ll/jetty-project

Jetty @ Github: (docbook documentation work, some test projects and the like)

https://github.com/jetty-project

Jetty Snapshot Repository: (nightly updates)

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/jetty/

CIA aggregate commit feed for all of jetty:

http://cia.vc/stats/project/jetty/

Comment: Tnx for the overview. What was of my primary interest was the source repo of the maven-jetty-plugin which I only found at git://git.codehaus.org/jetty-project.git and your mirror of this one at github. Maybe it is useful to point it our at a prominent place in the docs at Eclipse or Codehaus pages?

Comment: yes, I'll have it updated in the new documentation, sorry it was a pain to find

Comment: update 2016: https://github.com/jetty-project/codehaus-jetty-project/tree/master/jetty-maven-plugin

Comment: 2016: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.3.x/jetty-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Finally found it https://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/jetty-project/jetty-maven-plugin and here git://git.codehaus.org/jetty-project.git

Comment: To view online: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/master/jetty-maven-plugin